# Swift: Converting

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am struggling with converting between formats for dictionaries: 
I am trying to convert the item array below into the result Array below. Essentially by looking for duplicates in the items first element and then only adding files to the result set when the first parameter is different.

```
var items:[[String]] = [["a", "b"],["a", "c"],["b", "c"]]

var result:[[String:[String]]] = [
    ["a":["b","c"]],
     ["b":["c"]]
]
```

I have tried using a multitude of arrays however I keep hitting errors in my xcode.  Any idea what the best approach would be?

The for in loop always seems to come up one item short.  Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the results have to be an array, or can it just be a dictionary. var result:[String:[String]] = [
    "a":["b","c"],
     "b":["c"]
] ?

Comment: Actually a dictionary would work too

Comment: Why do you have a data structure consisting of 2 element arrays? Something seems fishy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a general case where the sub arrays in item can have more than on string. This also allows for empty arrays in the items array. This gives results ["a": ["b", "c", "g"], "b": ["c"], "c": []]

```
func testThree() {
    let items = [["a", "b"],["a", "c", "g"],["b", "c"],["c"]]
    var result:[String:[String]] = [:]

    for arr in items {
        if(arr.count > 0) {
            let first = arr[0]
            if(result[first] != nil) {
                result[first]!.append(contentsOf: arr[1..<arr.count])
            } else {
                result[first] = Array(arr[1..<arr.count])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all the redundant type annotations?

Comment: No reason. Remove them if you like.

Comment: They're generally discouraged in Swift, unless they actually contribute enough clarity to be worth the visual burden

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If `result` can be a dictionary - as you mentioned in your comment - you can do this:

```
var result = [String:[String]]()
items.forEach {
    if let entry = result[$0[0]] {
        result[$0[0]]?.append($0[1])
    } else {
        result[$0[0]] = [$0[1]]
    }
}
```

For the sake of readability you can also write it as:

```
var result = [String:[String]]()
for item in items {
    if let entry = result[item[0]] {
        result[item[0]]?.append(item[1])
    } else {
      result[item[0]] = [item[1]]
    } 
}
```

The [`items.forEach {...}`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689783-foreach) basically does the same thing as the regular `for..in` loop, just without the named variable (in this case `item`), so you'll have to access the current value using `$0`.

The result of this code will be

```
["a": ["b", "c"], "b": ["c"]]
```

Comment: Thanks I am not familiar with the items.foreach syntax - care to explain it in a bit more simplistic terms or link to where I can read about it ?

Comment: @MobileBloke I added an equivalent alternative (which I would actually prefer myself) and linked to the documentation for the `forEach(_:)` function.